# Why different version numbers displayed on different platforms?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-maui

Using Visual Studio 2022 Community edition, my .Net MAUI project file contains the following entry:

```
<ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.2.18</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
```

An XAML page contains a Label for displaying the version, as follows

```
 <Label
    Text="{Binding App_version}"
    FontSize="12"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
 />
```

The ViewModel contains the following code to get the version and set the label text:

```
App_version = AppInfo.VersionString;
```

When the project is run using the Windows Machine simulator, the version number displayed is  NOT correct, i.e.:

```
1.2.12.1
```

When the project is run using the Android simulator, the version number displayed is correct, i.e.:

```
1.2.18
```

Is this a bug, or is there some difference on how the version number is displayed on different platforms -- if so, where is this documented?

Comment: in the docs it says that for window it get it from `Package.appxmanifest ` Version on the Identity node [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/app-information?tabs=windows#platform-implementation-specifics),  i have `Version="0.0.0.0"` but in code it returns another version (always on windows) seems overwritten somewhere by maui.

Comment: this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5137) and related pr are related but seems to be old and already fixed